# How many different ways are there to create a "page"

Tags: 8

By page I mean what's served by a given route/url. Trying to understand all the options so I know what I can combine (e.g. create a View, and use a render alter hook to add a form at the bottom).

Here's my incomplete list:

- Controller
- View
- Form
- Backend creation of pages, articles, custom content types.
- Contact Forms
- ?

Comment: A route forwards to a method in a class, which (for the most part) returns a render array. Some of those routes are wrapped up in higher level concepts like nodes, views, contact forms, etc, but really the answer is there’s no such list - it depends what modules you have installed, and what functionality you’re using from them

Comment: This seems like a good documentation page more than a q&a.

Comment: Look at the D8 routing API docs and look at your `router` table for your D8 install. All your listed examples are just routes provided by different modules (including any custom modules where you're providing your own custom route controllers).